# Can I force the dropdown terminal on windows 10 to always open on a specific display?

Tags: windows-11, windows-terminal

When using the Dropdown terminal on windows 11, it always pulls down on the display where the mouse currently is (not important I think, but I use 3 displays).

I want to configure it to ALWAYS open on Display 1. I could not find any configuration option on windows.

Is it possible?

Comment: What is "Dropdown terminal"?

Comment: The quake style terminal that comes when you use WINKEY + '